# create custom character on lcd 20x4 using python code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to try to make a big character on LCD 20x4 with some python code.

I have previously displayed some data and text on LCD 16x2 with adafruit library, but now I am trying to display a custom character on LCD 20x4 and am a bit confused. I think the code below (from the adafruit library) is useful for making custom characters, but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone provide guidance on how to do this?

```
 def create_char(self, location, pattern):
    """Fill one of the first 8 CGRAM locations with custom characters.
    The location parameter should be between 0 and 7 and pattern should
    provide an array of 8 bytes containing the pattern. E.g. you can easyly
    design your custom character athttp://www.quinapalus.com/hd44780udg.html
    To show your custom character use eg. lcd.message('\x01')
    """
    # only position 0..7 are allowed
    location &= 0x7
    self.write8(LCD_SETCGRAMADDR | (location << 3))
    for i in range(8):
        self.write8(pattern[i], char_mode=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the tool in the link to generate a pattern, then pass the decimal version to this function as an list in the second argument, e.g.

```
lcd.create_char(1, [0,10,21,17,10,4,0])
```

to define character 1 as a heart. Once you've done this, you can include a `\x01` in a string to print that character.

As implied in the documentation, the same idea will work for any character code from 0 to 7. Just replace the first argument to `create_char()` with another number in that range.

Comment: how to print that character into lcd 16x2? can you give me an example? i have tried it, and give me an error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Oh, looks like the library wants 5x8. Add an extra `0` to the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

for some reason, it only works for me after I enter a new line character.

eg. `\n \x01` will print my character
`\x01` and any variation without \n first will not print my character.

No idea why. FYI, I'm using the 20x4 LCD.