# Get a matrix of 1's and 0's for character, in Python

Tags: python, arrays, ascii, lcd

Is there a way to get the bit array of an ASCII character without having to create a dictionary or list with the corresponding rows? only for the letters of the English alphabet, A-Z
[image: ASCII TABLE]

example:

```
input : "A"
 
A -> 01000001 -> [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], ... ]

output: [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], ... ]
```

EDIT:

[image: i want]

This is what I am looking for, an array with the values ​​to show the figure of the character "A" for example:

```py
# Press Ctrl+f "1" to see this better
[
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
]
```

Comment: "bit array of an ASCII character" doesn't make much sense: "an ASCII character" is an integer (like `01000001` in your post), while the image `A` you see on your screen is a glyph (not sure about terminology here) of a particular _font_. Different fonts have different glyphs (? basically, images for symbols), so you're looking for some kind of font data: https://docs.fileformat.com/font/

Comment: Please explain more clearly about what you need. Thanks

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew  As you can see, it is very easy to get the binary value of a character. but what I really need is an array with the "dots" to form the figure of "A"

Comment: In that case, perhaps you will need to provide a link or some materials for us to know more about this LCD table?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Of course, this is the page where I found information on this table. https://mil.ufl.edu/3744/docs/lcdmanual/characterset.html, edit: also add an edit to the question to make it clearer what I want to get.

Comment: This looks interesting, yet not in my area. I found some links that may help you https://www.google.com/search?q=adafruit+python and https://www.quinapalus.com/hd44780udg.html. Also one more SO post about LCD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017357/create-custom-character-on-lcd-20x4-using-python-code

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew thanks for your time, but I think I came to the conclusion that there is no "shortcut" to do this in a simple way :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture in your post (as far as I am concerned), you can always get the ASCII character using Python built-in function. And if you want to split up the binary strings, you can also use Python `join` function.

```
def binary_alphabet_split(astring):
    result = bin(int.from_bytes(astring.encode(), 'big'))
    result = result.replace('b', '')
    return [','.join(result)]

binary_alphabet_split('A')
Out[20]: ['0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1']
```

This will get you a list of split binary codes of the alphabet.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what I'm really looking for is not the binary value of the characters, but the bits of each row in the LCD table. What would be the "dots" that form the figure of the "A"